# How to Secure Content Type from Anonymous users in orchard?

Tags: security, orchardcms

I have added a page and now it should be only accesible for authenticated user.

What can be done to achieve this ?

Comment: Add an authentication/authorization scheme to your application?

Comment: Could you guide me a little on that @NiklasB. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature that is being added to Orchard 1.5 but you can already get the feature from the 1.x branch. There is also a module available from the gallery: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Downplay.Quanta

Comment: I am using orchard 1.6. How do I secure the content and allow it to be shown only for authenticated users. I do not want to install any modules from the gallery.

Comment: Why don't you want to install anything from the gallery? The http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.ContentPermissions module is completely official and is doing exactly what you want.

Comment: If the feature is part of Orchard out-of-the-box since 1.5, why should VolleyBall need to install anything from the gallery?  He says he's using 1.6.  Do you still need to install it if it's already a feature?

Comment: Because while the source code has all the official modules, the pre-built executable version doesn't.

Comment: Was anything changed for Orchard 1.9?

Comment: Lots of things were changed in 1.9. Do you have a more specific question? What kind of change are you looking for?

Comment: I'd like to create content type or content items that will not be accessible for anonymous users.

Comment: I find the standard way to secure content item. Need to use Content Item Permissions Module and Content Permissions Part. But may be there is a way to secure one content type?

Comment: The Content Permissions Part has a content type settings that can be used to configure permissions for all content item of this type. In content type settings page need to set permissions and uncheck all showed roles. But nevertheless need to check one checkbox for each content item to secure one.